# Regex to remove characters left and right of a certain word

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression to remove characters left and right of a certain word and stop at first encounter of ; from both sides

For example the below combinations should always return the same result, the word in this case is "url":

123url456 789;1;2

1;123url 456;2

1;2;()url()

1;2;88^url();

1;2;url789 999

url3772;1;2

**Result:**

1;2

**Two special cases**

;123url 123;

22 url123

should both return nothing

there are a lot of different scenarios to consider, when there is ; on both sides, when there is ; on left not right, when there is ; on right and not left, and when there is no ; on both sides.

Comment: Do you mean "both return the empty string"?

Comment: @virolino yes empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the regex:

```
;?[^;\n]*url[^;\n]*;?
```

and replace it with nothing. It fixes your problem.

However, the second line will not return what you expect because the input does not follow your rule. The second line should be something like:

```
1;123url 456;;2
```

for your expected result.

If you want something more complicated than that, you will need a longer program - and for that you need to ask another question, I guess.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/cRvzvG/1) the solution.

Comment: pointed me in the right direction